# Add thousand seperators for string value in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, format

I am parsing a string which contains a (money) value in a **varchar** format.

Formatting is always like this: `12345,75` (varchar). Another input value could thus be `32323232,98` and so on...

Desired output = `12.345,75` (doesn't have to be output as a varchar).
So what I need is dots as thousand separators, and a comma for separating the two decimals (input value always has 2 decimals).

My attempt:

```sql
DECLARE @Num varchar(50)

SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(numeric(10,2), REPLACE(@Num,',','.')), @Num, '#.00')
```

Error:

> The culture parameter '#.00' provided in the function call is not supported.

Using MS SQL Azure 2019

Comment: The *real* problem here is you're storing numerical data in a `varchar`. Fix your design, store numerical data in a numerical data type.

Comment: input is a JSON, i.e. a varchar.

Comment: @wabuffets JSON represents numbers as numbers. Storing then in JSON as strings is as wrong as storing them as strings in the database (`12345,75` is not a valid JSON number, `12345.75` is). SQL Server can parse JSON correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The `'nl-nl'` culture does exactly what you want.  So, try using the third argument to `format()`:

```
select format(1234567.888, '#,#.00', 'nl-nl')
```

Comment: They are, but passing `'#.00'` for the third argument.

Comment: @gordon while your query works for your own example, I don't see how it is applicable to my question. Can you elaborate? You are using dots as comma seperators, and this needs to work with commas, where a parameter Num such as 12345,75 is passed into SQL as a varchar.

Comment: @wabuffets Put your `CONVERT(...)` instead of the 1234567.888.

Comment: @Gserg I did SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(numeric(10,2),REPLACE(@Num,',','.'),@NUM,'#,#.00','nl-nl') yet still seems to appear problematic. Any clue here?

Comment: @wabuffets Fix your parentheses. Then observe how many parameters `format` has and how many you are passing. Then observe how many Gordon Linoff is passing.

Comment: @wabuffets . . . It is possible that I don't understand the question.  Sample data and desired results in tabular format is always helpful.